# How to convert double quote and back slash together to regex in scala sql

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying to convert val form a dataframe to regex for fitting it into contains method. Currently some of my rows of dataframe consist of particular string like bellow

```html
\"\"
```

I want these particular row to be removed I am using bellow code to filter it out

```js
filter(!$"KEY".contains("\"\""))   \\tired even this .contains('\"\"')
```

Since I have backslash and double inverted comma in my string I am not able to convert this to fit into my contains method. I have tried using \\ for single \ but still double inverted comma is being issue , also i have tried replacing the outer double inverted comma into single inverted comma but even that its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In most strings `"` and `\` are considered special characters so try the following:

```
filter(!$"KEY",contains("\\\"\\\""))
```